# Why Does the Same Site in Different SERPs Contain and Not Contain Google Sitelinks

Tags: google, search-results

Is there a way to get sitelinks on a Google SERP when searching on a site's name vs. the sites' web address?

Example, if you search "`twin city kings`", the first result is the website for Twin City Kings ***without sitelinks***.

But if you search "`twincitykings.com`", the first result is the website for Twin City Kings ***with sitelinks***.

Is it possible to get sitelinks on both SERPs?

Thanks for helping or clarifying.

Note: this question does not pertain to "how to get a sitelink". It pertains to why does the same site come up in different SERPs with and without Sitelinks.

Comment: Every search term is considered separately for the assignment of sitelinks: ["We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user."](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)

Answer (score 1):

Enough good links to the domain name `twincitykings.com` with an anchor text of `"twin city kings"` will result site links for "twin city kings" too.

Google "needs to know" that twincitykings.com=twin city kings for sure. competitors for these KW might make it more difficult.